# Precommit Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, git, npm, yarnpkg, pre-commit

I'm currently working on this website contribution: https://github.com/torontojs/torontojs.com/pull/44

I'm trying to get a pre-commit command to trigger which is referenced in my `package.json` as `eslint src --fix && git add -A`. I've run `yarn install` and `yarn upgrade` but it still doesn't seem to trigger.

When I try to run the command manually, I get the error of `Cannot find module 'eslint-config-minimal'` even though it's referenced in my `package.json` before I `yarn install`.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this issue?